# Conditionally forkJoin observables inside nested observable with a loop

Tags: angular, observable, angular2-observables

I'm fetching an array of tiles, where some of them have a configuration array. Those with configuration might have either option array(with options Object) or optionUrl, which points to rest endpoint. 
How to append those options to each tile, that has configuration and optionUrl?
I have tried flatMap and forkJoin, but seems like it never completes the request for optionsUrl. I've also tried mergeMap, without success.

Any ideas how to make it work?

Here's example tile structure with optionUrl:

```
    {
     id: "superTile",
     name: "Super Tile",
     configurations: [
       {
        param: "shopId", 
        optionsUrl: "rest/shops"
       },
       {
        param: "sortOrder",
        option: [
         {
           id: "Newest",
           text: "PROD_YEAR-DESC"
         },
         {
           id: "Rank",
           text: "RANKING-DESC"
         },
        ]
       }
      ]
     }
```

Here's my component:

```
ngOnInit(){
this._myService.getAllTiles()
    .subscribe((tiles: Tiles[]) => {
       this.tiles = tiles
  })
 }
```

My service:

```
 getAllTiles(): Observable<any>{
    return this._http
        .get(this._tilesUrl)
        .map((result) => result.json().data)
        .flatMap((tiles) => {

            tiles.map((tile) => {
                if (tile.configurations) {
                    return Observable.forkJoin(
                        tile.configurations.map((config) => {
                            if(config.optionsUrl) {
                                console.log(config);
                                   return this._http.get(config.optionsUrl)
                                        .map((result) => {
                                            let optionArray = [];
                                            config['option'] = optionArray;
                                            let jsonObj = result.json();
                                            let newOptions = jsonObj.data;

                                            console.log(newOptions);

                                            config['option'].push(newOptions);
                                            return config;
                                        })
                            } else {
                                return Observable.of(config);
                            }
                        })
                    )
                } else {
                    return Observable.of(tiles)
                }
            });
            return Observable.of(tiles);
            })
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your `flatMap` method. You are using js `map` to loop through the array, however you are not using the returned array that `map` creates. You are returning `Observable.of(tiles)` to flatMap every time, so that value is subscribed to every time. Instead you should return the array that `tiles.map` returns

```
.flatMap((tiles) => {
    let tilesObservables$ = tiles.map(// rest of map code);

    return Observable.forkJoin(tilesObservables$);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this somehow helped. Fork join was working after I did as you said, but then there was coming a problem with the second map on tile.configurations - when it didn't meet condition, it was just returning double tile or double config items. Temporarily I moved the options request to tile component - this works like charm, but I'm still curious about the forkJoin solution.

Comment: @Tina333 what do you mean by `double tile or double config items`? It looks like the code returns an http request based on optionsUrl or just the config

Comment: I mean it returns an array of following:
0: {tileObj}
1: {configObj}, {configObj}
2: {optionsObj}, {configObj},
3: {tileObj}
4: {configObj}, {configObj}
It looks like depending whether it meets the condition, it returns either a tileObj or config Objects. If I delete the return Observable.of(config) from else statement, it complains I provided undefined where stream was expected.

Comment: @Tina333 If you want to omit the configObj then you can add the filter method. `tile.configuration.filter(config => config.optionsUrl).map(config => ...)` This will filter out any configs that do not have an optionsUrl and will generate an array of observables of optionsObj